# Copy a table without tags using clipboard.js

Tags: clipboard.js

I'm currently using clipboard.js to copy a table, but this table have some fields with tags like  and when pasting the content it introduces a line break.

I don't know if it's possible to remove all the tags from copied text with clipboard.js?

I am using something like:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" id="export-btn" data-clipboard-target="#datTtable">Copy</a>

<table id="datTable" data-tableName="Test" class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td> dat10</br> Ok </td><td> dat11 </td></tr>
    <tr><td> dat20         </td><td> dat21 </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script>
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.info('Action:', e.action);
  console.info('Text:', e.text);
  console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);

  e.clearSelection();
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error('Action:', e.action);
  console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
</script>
```

BR and thank

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say Hello. ;)

Comment: What result are you getting from the current script, and what are you expecting instead?

Comment: I would like to copy table data:
 dat10 OK dat11
 dat20 dat21
but in the first data **dat10 OK** I have a line break due to </br>